Need clarification on matrix norm vs eigenvalues
In short, the paradox in my head is: if a matrix has eigenvalues < 1, how can it have norm > 1?
For simplicity, let's assume the matrix is $2 \times 2$, has 2 independent eigenvectors and 2 real eigenvalues less than 1. I am getting that there can be a vector $v$ such that $|v| < |Av|$. But if I express $v=a_1v_1 + a_2v_2$ in terms of the eigenvectors, I get $Av=a_1\lambda_1v_1 + a_2\lambda_2v_2$. Now, since the lambdas (eigenvalues) are < 1, doesn't it need to hold that $|Av| < |v|$? But it my case that doesn't hold, what am I missing?
Edit: Here's an example:
    A1 =np.array([
   [-2.6530,   -2.0349,   -3.2854,   -2.1526],
   [0.8610,    0.8198,    1.0735,    0.5543],
    [1.0144,    0.7933,    1.3374,    0.7416],
    [0.8593,    0.5078,    0.9669,    0.9810],
    ])

Eigenvalues are [-0.254,  0.40,  0.24,  0.1] but the norm is 6.

Do you have an example of a matrix with norm greater than 1 from a matrix with real eigenvalues lesser than 1

To make this concrete: what norm are you using? This has little to do with diagonalizability.  Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1000000000 \ 0 & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$.  What's lower bound on the norm of $A\mathbf e_2$?

I just added an example, albeit it is $4 \times 4$

@whpowell96 your statement relating eigenvalues to operator 2 norm is false for non-normal $A$.

@BaronYugovich you are using the Frobenius norm ( https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html ).  You should state this in the OP.  I think you would be happier looking at the Operator 2 norm ('ord = 2' in the link).  Setting aside a lot of other issues: the problem here is Frobenius norm (and Operator 2 norm) is unitarilly invariant (orthogonally invariant in reals).  But you are doing a sleight of hand when you change basis to write $v=a_1v_1 + a_2v_2$ since that is not an orthogonal basis in general. I.e. change of basis doesn't preserve norms in general.

I am not doing Frobenius, I did print (np.linalg.eig(A1.T@A1)), finding largest eigenvalue of $A_1^TA_1$., it is 6.01

FYI, this is the spectral norm, a.k.a. the operator norm generated by the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$.

The largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$ is not a norm, but the square of a norm.

Yes, fine, you get around 36 in this case, so the spectral norm is indeed around 6.

@BaronYugovich you need to explicitly state this stuff in the original post [not the comments].  For the record, after rounding to two decimal places, the Frobenius norm is $6.03$ and the spectral norm is $6.02$.  Neither of these rounds to $6.01$ and when you wrote "but the norm is 6" in the original post, well they both round to $6$.  We should not have to guess what you are doing here.

I see @whpowell96 has deleted comment that I explicitly pointed out to be false re: non-normal $A$.  However the earlier comment that says "The discrepancy you are describing only occurs when you don't have a full set of eigenvectors" is also wrong-- it is why I wrote to consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1000000000 \ 0 & \frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$ .  Yet that erroneous comment has 2 upvotes which is rather alarming.

To help you wrap your head around it, let's visualise the map
$$T(x, y) = (3x - 2y, y),$$
or if you prefer a matrix,
$$\pmatrix{3 & -2 \\ 0 & 1}.$$
You can verify that this has two eigenvectors, $(1, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$, corresponding to eigenvalues $3$ and $1$ respectively. Here is a plot of these eigenvectors, along with a circle of radius $2$.

Note: the grid lines align with the eigenspaces. What does this look like when it's transformed?

The two eigenvectors have been transformed based on their eigenvalues; the vector $(1, 1)$ remains unchanged (as its eigenvalue is $1$), while $(1, 0)$ has been stretched to $(3, 0)$. The ellipse is the above circle, transformed by $T$.
The purple circle has radius $6$; if the spectral norm of $T$ were equal to its greatest eigenvalue, i.e. $3$, we would expect to see the green ellipse lie entirely in the purple circle. That is, we would expect to see any vector of length $2$ to map to a vector of at most length $6$. Because the green ellipse falls outside the purple circle, we can visually see that the spectral norm is indeed greater than largest greatest eigenvalue.
Let's now drill down on a particular point on the blue circle that will map outside the purple circle. Consider:

Visualised in orange is the vector $(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2})$. In terms of the eigenbasis, it is written as the sum of $(2\sqrt{2}, 0)$ and $(-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$, shown in red. What does this look like when transformed?

So, what's happening here? In the original picture, $(2\sqrt{2}, 0)$ lies outside the blue circle, while the addition of $(-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$ compensates, bringing the resultant vector back onto the blue circle. When transformed, the $(2\sqrt{2}, 0)$ vector triples in length, but the $(-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$ vector does not. If we had tripled the $(-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$ vector, we would find that the resultant vector would end up on the purple circle; essentially we would have scaled the original picture by a factor of $3$. But, since we didn't scale $(-\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})$ by $3$, it doesn't quite bring the orange vector onto the purple circle. It remains outside the purple circle (and on the green ellipse).
As you can hopefully see, this is kind of thing can happen when your eigenspaces are not orthogonal. Indeed, the smaller the angle between your eigenspaces, the more pronounced the difference between the spectral norm and the largest eigenvalue may be. When a matrix is normal, i.e. it commutes with its transpose (e.g. symmetric matrices), the eigenspaces are orthogonal, and the spectral norm will be the absolute value of its largest eigenvalue. But, for more general diagonalisable matrices, this is not the case.
